# Android Click on button does not change the backgroud color

Tags: java, android

I want to change the background color of button, on button click, this code is not showing any error , neither it is working .

```
   capstone.setOnClickListener(new HandleClick());
}
    private class HandleClick implements View.OnClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Button btn = (Button) v;
            String text = btn.getText().toString();
            btn.setBackgroundResource(R.color.btnClick);
            Log.d("color", R.color.btBackground + ""); // D/color: 2131427344
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
```

The Log.d() shows the value of color, but the color of button does not changed.

Comment: It was just a silly mistake, I was using same background color as default and on button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**We can use this, as It will get the default background color when the unclick the button. Or we can use the code what I have posted in answer, the problem was I was using same color as default as well as on button click.**

```
     capstone.setOnTouchListener(new HandleTouch());
    }   

 private class HandleTouch implements  View.OnTouchListener{
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Button btn = (Button) v;
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                btn.setBackgroundResource(R.color.btnClick);
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                btn.setBackgroundResource(R.color.btBackground);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`setBackgroundResource(int)` method is waiting for a drawable object. If you'd like to use colors, use the appropriate method which is `setBackgroundColor(int)`

and call `btn.invalidate();` after that

More details on Android Developers
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource(int)

Comment: I tried `btn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.btBackground));` but that does not solved the problem.

Comment: try to add this after setting background color : `btn.invalidate();`

Comment: I have 6 buttons so, when I am clicking the second button, both of them are having same color, I need to change the first's color to default, would you like to help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107474/discussion-between-prafulla-kumar-sahu-and-mehdi).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use a color resource as the background color of a view, you will need to get the ARGB color from resources using [getColor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor%28int,%20android.content.res.Resources.Theme%29), then set that in [setBackgroundColor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor%28int%29).

```
btn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.btBackground, null));
```

Comment: still no change in color, I had just copied your code and replaced mine, can you suggest , if there is anything else I should change ?

Comment: How have you defined R.color.btBackground?  What are you expecting to see?

Comment: yes `<color name="btnClick">#C51162</color>` is the color in colors.xml.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu but in your code you have mentioned R.color.btBackground where as its name is btnClick in xml as you just mentioned in the comment

Comment: that is too in colors.xml `   <color name="btBackground">#F57F17</color>` wait, I think i got it.

Answer (score 0):

The function `setBackgroundResource` will render the button.

try

```
setBackground(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btBackground))
```

Comment: I have not done anything in drawable , will it still work ?